# URLEncoder encode / URLDecoder decode in java (Android)

Tags: java, android

I want to use the URLEncoder/URLDecoder class (java.net.URLEncoder/URLDecoder) in an application and the methods : encode(String s, String enc)/decode(String s, String enc), but I don't know what can be the value of the String argument enc?
I want to encode/decode in the "x-www-form-urlencoded" MIME content type.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The encoding parameter is the character encoding you're using. `For example "UTF-8"`.

Comment: So I have to write it like that : encode("hello","x-www-form-urlencoded") or for "x-www-form-urlencoded" it's encode("hello","UTF-8")?

Comment: You have to write encode("hello","UTF-8"). x-www-form-urlencoded is always the type of the result. The encoding parameter refers to your input data.

Comment: Is there a predefined constant for the possible character encodings?

Comment: android documentation is SO bad! URLEncoder class documentation doesn't even mention "UTF-8"  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 4):

First you need to set the content-type as a 'x-www-form-urlencoded'. Then whatever content you would like to encode, encode it using "UTF-8".

For example:

**For setting content to 'x-www-form-urlencoded':**

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.xyz.com/SomeContext/SomeAction"); <br>
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();<br>
....<br>
....<br>
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Or if you are using some JSP then you can write the following on top of it.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %><br>
< META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


< FORM action="someaction.jsp" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="InputForm" method="POST">
```

**And to use URLEncoder:**

```
String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode("hello","UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have done :
- HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url");
- post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form- urlencoded");
- String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode("hello","UTF-8");
- StringEntity temp;
- temp.setContentEncoding(encodedString);
- post.setEntity(temp);
and then execute a DefaultHttpClient with post for argument.

Comment: The problem was really due to the fact that I put "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "UTF-8" in encode(String s, String enc)...
Again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) has all the details

Comment: The JavaDoc doesn't mention all of the possible encoding formats nor do I see a link to an ENUM which might list them.

Answer (score 0):

`URLEncoder` and `URLDecoder` both are exception `Throwable` and thus must be at least enclosed by try/catch block. However there is a litle bit simplier way using `android.net.Uri`:

```
Uri.decode(string);
Uri.encode(string);
```

Those are static methods, uses utf-8, available since API-1 and throws no exception.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite:

```
static String baseNameFromURL(URL url) {
    String shortName;
    String path = url.getPath();
    String escaped = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    try {
        shortName = URLDecoder.decode(escaped, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new Error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    int period = shortName.lastIndexOf('.');
    return period > -1 ? shortName.substring(0, period) : shortName;
}
```

Returns an empty String if the URL doesn’t have a file name part, like `https://stackoverflow.com/` or `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/`. If there is a backslash in the file name part, it is conserved.

You may strip off the last two lines if you need the short name with extension instead.