# convert string encoding in android

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, encoding

i want to get name and last name of application users by EditText view and send it to soap webservice to store in data base , i have problam when users enter data in arabic or persian it save data like this "?????" i try this code change encoding befor send data via webservice :

`newLastName = new String(URLEncoder.encode(lastname.getText().toString(), "UTF-8"));`

but when i check the encoding of  string in server side with this code :

```
return mb_detect_encoding($lastName);
```

it`s return me ASCII !

how can i slove this problam ?
thanks

i send "سلام" to webservice and its return me "????"  my problem is in php encoding system or in java encoding system ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the URLDecoder.decode() function, like this:

String s = URLDecoder.decode(myString, "UTF-8");

more info [string encoding easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896721/urlencoder-encode-urldecoder-decode-in-java-android)

Comment: i use this code for SoapObject property : request.addProperty("name2", URLDecoder.decode("سلام", "UTF-8) , but it,s not work and place this ???? in database